# i am unable to multiply add or do any mathematical operation in python with "StringVar" and "intvar"

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

root = Tk()

# Width x Height
root.geometry("1366x768")#it will be the starting size

# width, height
root.minsize() #it will be the minimum size


# width, height
root.maxsize() #it will be the maximum size

#setting tittle
root.title("Calculator")

#telling user what to give input
Heading=Label(root, text = "Multiplication" , font = "Azonix 16 bold").grid(row=1,column=1)
input1_Label=Label(root, text = "enter the first factor" , font = "Azonix 12 ").grid(row=2,column=1)
input2_Label=Label(root, text = "enter the second factor" , font = "Azonix 12 ").grid(row=3,column=1)


#getting input from the user
input1 = IntVar()
input1_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=input1).grid(row=2,column=2)
input2 = IntVar()
input2_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=input2).grid(row=3,column=2)

answer = input1*input2
answer_label = Label(root, text=answer)
answer_label.grid(row=4,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Error coming :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Codes\Main Projects\GUI Calculator.py", line 39, in <module>
    answer = input1*input2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntVar' and 'IntVar'
```

Please help me with the problem because I mostly work with a graphics user interface based things in python and adding things or doing basic mathematical operations is a necessary task for programmers like me

Comment: The names are somewhat misleading; an `IntVar` is only a *container* for an integer value, not usable as an integer value itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to extract the actual numerical value from the `IntVar`.

```
answer = input1.get() + input2.get()
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro it helped me a lot